# Insert results of a stored procedure into an existing table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert, routines

I have a table called Percentages with a Column called 5StarResults, I would like to populate this with the results of a stored procedure names 5star.

When I use 'Call 5star' it returns just a percentage, I would like this percentage inserted into the Percentages table.

Please can you assist, I have tried to edit the procedure to include an Insert but it always returns saying 0 rows inserted.

Thank you

edit,

Stored Procedure is as follows

```sql
BEGIN
  declare Rating5Total int default 5;
  declare Rating5Win int default 5;
  declare 5StarPerformance decimal;
  set Rating5Total = (select COUNT(Ratings) from vHighPerformance where Ratings = 7);
  set Rating5Win = (select COUNT(Results) from vHighPerformance where Ratings = 7 and Results = 1);
  set 5StarPerformance = Rating5Win*100.0/Rating5Total;
  Select 5StarPerformance;
END
```

Comment: You can post the code for the stored procedure `5star`?

Comment: you'r going to need to use a temp table, let me try to mock something up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an option is to do the INSERT in the same stored procedure, the following code should work:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `5star`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE Rating5Total INT DEFAULT 5;
    DECLARE Rating5Win INT DEFAULT 5;
    DECLARE 5StarPerformance DECIMAL(18, 3);
    SET Rating5Total := (SELECT COUNT(Ratings) FROM vHighPerformance WHERE Ratings = 7);
    SET Rating5Win := (SELECT COUNT(Results) FROM vHighPerformance WHERE Ratings = 7 AND Results = 1);
    SET 5StarPerformance := Rating5Win*100.0/Rating5Total;
    /* INSERT INTO percentages (percentage) VALUES (5StarPerformance); */
    INSERT INTO percentages (id, percentage) VALUES (1, 5StarPerformance)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE percentage = 5StarPerformance;
    SELECT 5StarPerformance;
END$$
```

An example can be seen in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff5f4/1).

**UPDATE**

If you need one single record on table `percentages`, you can make a UPSERT. See the updated code.

Comment: Is it possible with an UPDATE as every time it runs it adds a new row.  thanks